# Any downside to using SimpleTemplateResponse instead of render_to_string

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django (and python) and I've inherited a Django 1.8 codebase that renders templates with loader.render_to_string(). In order to call some middleware upon every template render, I'd like to refactor loader.render_to_string() to SimpleTemplateResponse, as follows:

before:

```
return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(self.tmpl + _file, kwargs))
```

after:

```
return SimpleTemplateResponse(self.tmpl + _file, kwargs)
```

From some quick testing, it seems that this change has no negative impact on our system. Can anyone with Django experience weigh in here? Are there any downsides to my desired refactor?

Comment: That change looks safe to me.